# Connecting python trading bot to MetaTrader5

Tags: python, metatrader5

I am constructing a trading bot on python and having trouble connecting it to MetaTrader5. The python version is 3.10

Here is a link to code I had trouble copy and pasting it here :https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EkbF5squLUVTMd2-9m19ObjU6qtKub3lKODKytSZSaY/edit?usp=sharing

I tired setting up a connect function based off of the MetaTrader website.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.